# Send live stream (continuously) to FTP

Tags: c#, html, video, ftp, live-streaming

I was searching about how to send live stream to FTP using C#...
I am finding only files or videos.. How can I send continuous live stream to FTP?
and how can I generate a link on FTP to serve the clients (html5)?
Please give sugestions or examples..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's not primarily a C# question: FTP is for storing and retrieving files, so while there might be FTP servers where you are still sending a file with STOR and at the same time retrieve it from another client with RETR I would not count on it that it works reliable or even with all servers.
So for live streams FTP is definitely not the protocol you should use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. I am trying different things around.. Recently I have worked on IpCamera, on for that camera they have provided live stream using ftp. My problem is I have to send live video stream from C# to HTML5 client. It would be great if you have any suggestions for my problem? Thank you....